# How far from its equilibrium position does the mass travel?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

An elastic band is hung on a hook and a mass is hung on the lower end of the band. When the mass is pulled downward and then released, it vibrates vertically. The equation of motion is 
s = 2 cos(t) + 9 sin(t), t ≥ 0,
 where s is measured in centimeters and t in seconds. (Take the positive direction to be downward.)

I've found the velocity by taking the derivative of s. --> -2sin(t)+9cos(t).

How do I use it to solve the following: How far from its equilibrium position does the mass travel?

Comment: Do you want to find the maximum distance from it's equilibrium position?

Comment: @Raptor yes please

Comment: Find $t$ when $v=0$ and use that value of $t$ to calculate $s$

Comment: Would t be tan^-1(-2/9)?

Comment: Yes, that is what $t$ equals.

Comment: What would that value be? My calculator shows an error

Comment: My bad, I didn't read it thoroughly. $v=-2\sin t+9\cos t=0\implies 2\sin t=9\cos t\implies \tan t=\frac 92 \implies t=\arctan {\left( \frac 92 \right)}$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!